# Mmap DMA memory uncached: "map pfn ram range req uncached-minus got write-back"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

I am mapping DMA coherent memory from kernel to user space. At user level I use `mmap()` and in kernel driver I use `dma_alloc_coherent()` and afterwards `remap_pfn_range()` to remap the pages. This basically works as I can write data to the mapped area in my app and verify it in my kernel driver.

However, despite using dma_alloc_coherent (which should alloc uncached memory) and `pgprot_noncached()` the kernel informs me with this `dmesg` output:

> map pfn ram range req uncached-minus for [mem 0xABC-0xCBA], got write-back

In my understanding, write-back is cached memory. But I need uncached memory for the DMA operation.

The Code (only showing the important parts):

**User App**

```
fd = open(dev_fn, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
if (fd > 0)
{
    mem = mmap ( NULL 
               , mmap_len
               , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
               , MAP_SHARED
               , fd
               , 0
               );
}
```

For testing purposes I used `mmap_len = getpagesize()`; Which is `4096`.

**Kernel Driver**

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t     mem_size;
    dma_addr_t dma_addr;
    void       *cpu_addr;
} Dma_Priv;

fops_mmap()
{
    dma_priv->mem_size = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;

    dma_priv->cpu_addr = dma_alloc_coherent ( &gen_dev
                                            , dma_priv->mem_size
                                            , &dma_priv->dma_addr
                                            , GFP_KERNEL
                                            );
    if (dma_priv->cpu_addr != NULL)
    {
        vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
        remap_pfn_range ( vma
                        , vma->vm_start
                        , virt_to_phys(dma_priv->cpu_addr)>>PAGE_SHIFT
                        , dma_priv->mem_size
                        , vma->vm_page_prot
                        )
    }
}
```

**Useful information I've found**

1. [PATting Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2008/ols2008v2-pages-135-144.pdf):

   Page 7 --> mmap with *O_SYNC* (**uncached**):

   > Applications can open /dev/mem with the O_SYNC flag and then do mmap
   > on it. With that, applications will be accessing that address with an
   > uncached memory type. mmap will succeed only if there is no other
   > conflicting mappings to the same region.

   I used the flag, doesn't help.

   Page 7 --> mmap without *O_SYNC* (**uncached-minus**):

   > mmap without O_SYNC, no existing mapping, and not a write-back region:
   > For an mmap that comes under this category, we use uncached-minus type
   > mapping. In the absence of any MTRR for this region, the effective
   > type will be uncached. But in cases where there is an MTRR, making
   > this region write-combine, then the effective type will be
   > write-combine.
2. **`pgprot_noncached()`**

   In `/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h` I found this:

   ```
    #define pgprot_noncached(prot)                              \
        ((boot_cpu_data.x86 > 3)                                \
         ? (__pgprot(pgprot_val(prot) |                         \
                 cachemode2protval(_PAGE_CACHE_MODE_UC_MINUS))) \
         : (prot))
   ```

Is it possible that x86 always sets a noncached request to UC_MINUS, which results in combination with MTRR in a cached write-back?

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04.1**, Kernel: **4.10.0-40-generic**.

Comment: Don't you need to cast `dma_priv->cpu_addr`? It's `void*` but `set_memory_uc` is expecting `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/pat.txt

> Drivers wanting to export some pages to userspace do it by using mmap
> interface and a combination of 1) pgprot_noncached() 2)
> io_remap_pfn_range() or remap_pfn_range() or vmf_insert_pfn()
>
> With PAT support, a new API pgprot_writecombine is being added. So,
> drivers can continue to use the above sequence, with either
> pgprot_noncached() or pgprot_writecombine() in step 1, followed by
> step 2.
>
> In addition, step 2 internally tracks the region as UC or WC in
> memtype list in order to ensure no conflicting mapping.
>
> Note that this set of APIs only works with IO (non RAM) regions. If
> driver wants to export a RAM region, it has to do set_memory_uc() or
> set_memory_wc() as step 0 above and also track the usage of those
> pages and use set_memory_wb() before the page is freed to free pool.

I added `set_memory_uc()` before `pgprot_noncached()` and it did the thing.

```
if (dma_priv->cpu_addr != NULL)
{
    set_memory_uc(dma_priv->cpu_addr, (dma_priv->mem_size/PAGE_SIZE));
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
    remap_pfn_range ( vma
                    , vma->vm_start
                    , virt_to_phys(dma_priv->cpu_addr)>>PAGE_SHIFT
                    , dma_priv->mem_size
                    , vma->vm_page_prot
                    )
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53196359/2) to the question [Mmap DMA memory uncached: "map pfn ram range req uncached-minus got write-back"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196359/mmap-dma-memory-uncached-map-pfn-ram-range-req-uncached-minus-got-write-back) by the OP [Gbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5659094/gbo) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>